# How to provide the ID to the Textbox that is inside the Datagrid's datatemplate in wpf in mvvm model, So that I can differentiate the textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

In My WPF Application I am using MVVM Model. Datagrid Contains Textbox and Label,  when provide the input at the run time in the Textbox, dynamically a description will show in label as per the input in the same row.

But the problem is when I provided the input to a textbox, all the textbox with in the datagrid reflect the same input value as their id is not different in grid. how can I  solve this problem.

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="c1DataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding CreditInfo}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Credit" Binding="{Binding Path=Credit}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Percentage">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>

                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.CreditPercentage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                            <b:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <b:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                                    <b:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding Path= DataContext.LostFocusCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">                                          
                                    </b:InvokeCommandAction>
                                </b:EventTrigger>
                            </b:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Width="440" Text="{Binding PercentageDescription}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: So you have a `CreditInfo` collection on your VM, and each item of that has a `Credit` property and a `PercentageDescription` property. On the VM itself you have a `CreditPercentage` property, which is updated whenever you change *any* of the 'Percentage' columns in your datagrid ... all those 'percentage' textboxes are bound to the same VM property. Is that correct? Are you trying to make it such that each item in the CreditInfo collection has its own `CreditPercentage` value?

Comment: No doubt credit info collection bind the first column. but the second column is not dependent on the first column, but the percentage description is dependent on the insert value in the second column( Cerdit percentage). The calculation is working fine, but the problem is it display the same content what ever entered in any of the textbox , that is in the second column. my question is how to restrict the content of the textbox in the same textbox, not in the other textbox i:e present in the below rows. if you need I will send the code also. Thanks of your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your code correctly you have a grid with 3 columns. The first column contains some value the second column contains textbox where you can insert a value and the third column contains a textbox that calculates percentage of the first column value taking second column value as the percent.

i.e. you have Credit=50 you type 10 into the second column's textbox and you want 5 to appear in the third column.

If that's correct then there is an easier way to achieve what you want.

You create two new properties in the view model for the items bound to your grid. The first property will contain whatever is entered into the textbox of the second column:

```
    private int _creditPercentage;

    public int CreditPercentage
    {
        get { return _creditPercentage; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _creditPercentage)
                return;

            _creditPercentage= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CreditPercentage");
            OnPropertyChanged("PercentageDescription");
        }
    }
```

The second property is going to contain the result of the calculation:

```
public String PercentageDescription
{
    get { return Convert.ToString(Math.Round((double)Credit*Percentage/100), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
}
```

Now you bind the Percentage property to your TextBox in the second column. And PercentageDescription to your third column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Percentage">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding CreditPercentage}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

<DataGridTextColumn  Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Path=PercentageDescription}"/>
```

You might also want to implement some input validation in that textbox in the second column to insure that user can only enter digits.

Comment: doing the calculation is not an important part. My problem is displaying the value in the textbox. What ever I entered the value,  in the percentage Textbox column of the Datagrid, it reflect in all the textboxs of the entire datagrid. My question is how to restrict the entered percentage value with in the same row textbox, not in the entire datagrid. Hope you understand. I tried your suggestion but it not worked for me.

Comment: The problem with your code is that you bind whatever is entered into the textbox to a single property of a DataContext of the whole page.

Instead you need to bind it to the property inside the item that is displayed in each row of your grid.

You need to create property CreditPercentage in the view model of your item (the same place where you have property "Credit") and then change the binding of your TextBox text property to:
{Binding CreditPercentage}

After that you need to change your third column to be bound to that same CreditPercentage (no need to change template also)

Comment: its worked for me by applying the OnPropertyChanged("CreditPercentage"); in the creditinfo property, also define the percentageDescription property in cerditmodel.public ObservableCollection<Credits> CreditInfo
        {
            get
            {
                return infos;
            }
            set
            {

                infos = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CreditInfo");
                OnPropertyChanged("CreditPercentage");
                //OnPropertyChanged("PercentageDescription");
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

its worked for me by applying the OnPropertyChanged("CreditPercentage"); in the creditinfo property, also define the percentageDescription property in creditmodel.

```
 public ObservableCollection<Credits> CreditInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return infos;
        }
        set
        {

            infos = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CreditInfo");
            OnPropertyChanged("CreditPercentage");
            //OnPropertyChanged("PercentageDescription");
        }
    }public string PercentageDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return percentageDescription;
        }
        set
        {
            percentageDescription = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PercentageDescription");
        }
    }
```