# How to get textbox text which has placed in datagrid column header in wpf

Tags: wpf

I want to have a datagrid with textbox in each colunmns header to filter datagrid.
I tried read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099042/filter-wpf-datagrid-values-from-a-textbox) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380049/how-to-provide-the-id-to-the-textbox-that-is-inside-the-datagrids-datatemplate) . here's my datagrid:

```
 <DataGrid  x:Name="CustomersDataGrid" BorderThickness="1" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
              CanUserAddRows="False" 
              CanUserResizeColumns="True" 
              CanUserResizeRows="False" 
              CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
              SelectionMode="Single" 
              SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
              DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="CustomersDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Customer.Name}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Name" Style="{StaticResource GridTitleLabel}"/>
                            <TextBox Name="NameTextBox" MinWidth="100" TextChanged="SearchTextBox_TextChanged" Text="{Binding FilterString, ElementName=UI, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

and this is filterstring in codebehind:

```
private string _filterString;
    public string FilterString
    {
        get { return _filterString; }
        set
        {
            _filterString = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FilterString");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

but a cant get textBox text , it doesn't bind correctly and filterstring value is always null

Comment: What is "UI" in your XAML?

Comment: this is x:Name value of my window

Answer (score 1):

As i understand, you does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your Window.
Let me show you little example:
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="FilterSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Name="window"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="120">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                                       Content="Some header" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                                         Text="{Binding Filter, ElementName=window, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _filter;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Filter
    {
        get { return _filter; }
        set
        {
            if (_filter == value) return;
            _filter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Then it's magic :) Try to change Binding Mode on TwoWay and/or add some DebugConverter to check if Binding is fired or not.

Answer (score 0):

When you write "Binding" the property "Filter" must be in the DataContext.
However, the textbox does not have direct access to DataContext why is within the GridView.

So, do something like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.Filter, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: I use this textbox to filter datagrid, not to showing data. did you check two mentioned links? binding can use for bind to a property.

Comment: You can just change Mode=OneWayToSource to Mode=OneWay if you don't want show data. Have you tested my answer?

Comment: as I said, I dont want to bind it to a field of datacontext !! I want to use it to filter datagrid.